# Using Jekinsfile with "pipeline script from SCM" failed when using git fetch inside Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins

I have a Jenkinsfile and inside of it there is a "git" command to fetch the sourcecode of my java service. also I created a job with "pipeline script from SCM" to fetch the jenkinsfile from git.
However when use some specific commands like git show to findout commit message, failure happens. Commit message show the git  of main pipeline, instead of git that is fetch inside of Jenkinsfile

Comment: this question would probably be more appropriate for DevOps or Stack Overflow, see https://meta.superuser.com/questions/13805/should-we-do-something-about-the-high-number-of-jenkins-questions-with-no-votes

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer by myself. 
When run a jenkins with "pipeline script from SCM" to get Jenkinsfile from Git, all the git commands that i used on that Jenkinsfile, returned current Git fetch.
As I said, inside the Jenkinsfile, i use another git command to fetch my service inside Jenkinsfile. to reach the git commit message of the git, I used the below command.

git log --format=%H -n 1